# HTML/CSS fixed/absolute layout (that auto-scales)

Tags: html, css

I have a 1024x768 background image that I want to place a table over so the cells of the table align with a "grid" in the background image.

This would be sort of easy with judicious use of margins and padding, etc.

The problem is I would like the background image (or *floating* image) to auto-scale/size and hold it's aspect ratio. (This is easy, too).

However, I can't figure out how to get the table to properly and always align itself to the image, even when the size of the window (and thus the image changes).

What I *really* want to do is to just sort of say "make this entire layout (including the table) 1024x768 - but then scale the complete rendered page up-or-down to suit the window size.

Seems kind of simple - but can't figure it out...

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you are working with or at least a codepen or fiddle?

Comment: I saw how to do the image scaling here http://jsfiddle.net/GHmz7/4/ - but when I started playing with putting a table on top, I quickly realized it wasn't going to work...